# Easier way to loop through controls to create SQL string?

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am filtering a sub form by looping through all controls on a page to created the record source of said sub form. It works great when controls match the field names, then if I cant have the control name matching it grows a little with sme specific VBA for that control name but im happy with it, it gets very long winded though when I try to have multiple controls working on a single field as I need to include every possible combination and Im wondering if there may be an easier way like a loop through the related controls.

What I mean is if I want filter to   but allow them to select up to 4 people at a time so the controls are Assigned_to_1 , 2 , 3 ,4    all there to build the where condition on the field    It works fine covering every out come in a chain of if's its just very long and hard to go to to make alteration or additions does anyone know a a way I may be able to simplify this?

The where that im currently building I of the format  -

```
     (Assigned_to =  Assigned_to ='" & Assigned_to & "' Or Assigned_to ='" & Assigned_to_2& "')
```

Obviously it only includes those controls that have an input in the building of the string.  Perhaps something along the lines of a loop through controls using a wildcards to build a strong to add to main string?

Answer (score 3):

A `Tag` property of control is very useful for such kind tasks. You can put here column name. If you need more parameters, you can use strings like "key1=value1|key2=value2" and analyze them in the controls loop.

Comment: Didn't think to use the tag as the common I think ive built the solution ill just test it, posted as an answer

Answer (score 1):

Solution found, below is working filter code should others find value in it.

```
    Dim strFilter As String
Dim ctL As Access.Control
Dim StrSQL As String
 Dim StrASS As String
For Each ctL In Me.Controls

 If Not IsNull(ctL) And ctL.Tag <> "" Then
     If (ctL.Tag = "Assigned_Officer") Then
        If StrASS = "" Then
        StrASS = "AND (Assigned_Officer = '" & ctL & "'"
        Else
        StrASS = StrASS & " Or Assigned_Officer = '" & ctL & "'"
        End If
    Else
    strFilter = strFilter & " AND " & ctL.Name & " = "
        If ctL.Tag = "text" Then
        strFilter = strFilter & "'" & ctL & "'"
        Else
        strFilter = strFilter & ctL
        End If
    End If
    End If
Next
    If Not StrASS = "" Then
     StrASS = StrASS & ")"
    strFilter = strFilter & StrASS
    End If
StrSQL = "<Select statement with a fixed where on it>" & Strfilter
Me.<subform>.Form.RecordSource = StrSQL
end Sub
```